# A & B don't/doesn't exist translation

Tags: word-usage

How to say or write
"A & B don't exist" in formal and informal form with involving the word 存在 ?

Answer (score 1):

1. AもBも存在しない、 AとBは存在しない、AやBは存在しない、AやBなどは存在しない
2. AもBも存在しません、 AとBは存在しません、AやBは存在しません、AやBなどは存在しません

Comment: Hi there, welcome to JLSE, and thanks for providing an answer to the question posed! In the future, I'd recommend you offer a bit more explanation in your posts, as that way the post is more useful in helping other members of the community to learn, rather than simply answering the question posed. The community guidelines have a little more detail on how to answer questions "well", if you haven't read those already. See: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer. Hope that all makes sense. Thanks again and welcome once more to JLSE!